# How to pre-render a letter with action mailer in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send an exactly the same email to a bunch of users.

What I do now is:

```rb
emails.each { |em| MyMailer.letter(em).deliver_later }
```

The problem with that is that now for every single email, it will re-render the whole letter again and again (it's using the mjml to do this, so it's not fast). But I know that the email is exactly the same for all users, so can I sorta pre-render the template, so it only renders once?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not send one email to all the emails ids?

Comment: @SandipMane how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Send it to multiple recipients using

```
mail(to: User.admin.pluck(:email), subject: "Hello Admins!")
```

This will send it to all the admins.
Check [the doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-to-multiple-recipients) for more info on this.

Comment: Thanks! There's a problem with that though, now all the emails will be visible to everyone in the thread. What I'd like to do is to send each email separately

Comment: Yea, if thats a requirement then you need to send the emails separately. 
You could do one more thing, generate the body once and pass it on to the mailer.
`mail` method accepts `body` argument too.

Comment: Instead of using the `to:` key just use the `bcc:` key which will send the mail to everyone, but won't reveal the email addresses of anyone.